# Range of partial autocorrelation function

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

What is the range of the pacf function in python? I'd assumed it'd be [-1,1] like Pearson's correlation and autocorrelation, but on trying on my data, I see it has values like -5.

Can anyone tell me why pacf has a different range, and what exactly is this range?

Edit :

the functions I'm using are -

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf, plot_acf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import pacf, acf
```

I'm using the data from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting) hackathon. This a timeseries of weekly sales across different stores and departments. I have checked the pacf values for data of 1 store, 1 dept

Here's the code for getting the pacf values :

```
# getting the data for just one store & dept
s1d1 = data[(data.Store==1)&(data.Dept==1)].sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

# differencing the series by 1 to make it stationary
s1d1['Weekly_Sales_shifted'] = s1d1.Weekly_Sales.shift(1)
s1d1['Weekly_Sales_differenced'] = s1d1.Weekly_Sales - s1d1.Weekly_Sales_shifted

# dropping the first record since it will have a nan in differenced column
s1d1 = s1d1.dropna(axis=0, subset='Weekly_Sales_differenced', how='any')

# getting the pacf values
pacf_values = pacf(s1d1['Weekly_Sales_differenced'], nlags=53)
```

Comment: Which library are you using? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Gulzar - I have added an edit in my post, with these details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PACF function in statsmodels.tsa.stattools gives numbers greater than 1 when using ywunbiased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252492/pacf-function-in-statsmodels-tsa-stattools-gives-numbers-greater-than-1-when-usi)